# Which version of xpath that Nokogiri support?

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I can't find an official statement of the xpath version that Nokogiri supports. Anyone can help me  with it? In fact I want to extract some elements that have an attribute start with specified sub string. For example, I want to get all `Book` elements that have a `category` attribute start with the character `C`. How to do this with nokogiri?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy?-->
<bookstore>

<book category="COOKING">
  <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
  <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>30.00</price>
</book>

<book category="CHILDREN">
  <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
  <author>J K. Rowling</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>29.99</price>
</book>

<book category="WEB">
  <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
  <author>James McGovern</author>
  <author>Per Bothner</author>
  <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
  <author>James Linn</author>
  <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price>49.99</price>
</book>

<book category="WEB">
  <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
  <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price>39.95</price>
</book>

</bookstore>
```

Comment: ["Nokogiri only supports XPath 1.0 and does not support XPath 2.0, which tokenize() was first defined in."](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/957). The limitations are due to libxml2 and javax.xml.xpath

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know which specific version of XPath Nokogiri supports. But, you can do this:

> I want to get all `book` elements that have a `category` attribute start with the character `C`.

using XPath's [`starts-with`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-starts-with):

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(your_xml)
doc.search('//book[starts-with(@category, "C")]').each { |e| puts e['category'] }
# output is:
# COOKING
# CHILDREN
```

You could also use a CSS3 ["begins with" selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings):

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(your_xml)
doc.search('book[category^=C]').each { |e| puts e['category'] }
# output is:
# COOKING
# CHILDREN
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up here looking for Nokogiri's xpath version.

In the end I found out that the current version (1.15.3) mounts xpath version 1.0.

Source: https://nokogiri.org/#features-overview.

Comment: Could you please provide the specific `Nokogiri` version that you referenced? It is advisable to provide answers that remain relevant and do not become outdated quickly.

Comment: Updated as requested ;)