# Is it possible to use XPath 3.0 in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xpath

I have been reading about [XPath version 3.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-30/) and like its new features, but I couldn't find any way to use it within Ruby on Rails. Does anybody know of a way to get XPath 3 working in Rails?

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is Nokogiri. But I don't see what XPath version is supported and [I seem not to be the only one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199463/which-version-of-xpath-that-nokogiri-support). So you need to pick a 3.0 specific feature and try it out with Nokogiri, I fear.

Answer (score 0):

If you use JRuby, you could add support for XPath 3.0 by using the Saxon java library.

Taken from the Saxon documentation site:

> Saxon 9.5 implements the XPath 3.0 specification as defined in the Candidate Recommendation of 8 January 2013
>
> [Source](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/conformance/xpath30.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is a [ruby binding](https://github.com/BaseXdb/basex-api/tree/master/src/main/ruby) for [BaseX](http://www.basex.org), but you will have to run BaseX as a service. Using JRuby you might be able to embed it (BaseX is Java software).

BaseX implements XQuery 3.0, which is a superset of XPath 3.0.

There might also be ruby bindings for other XQuery processors and XML databases, you might want to have a look at Saxon, eXist DB, Sedna and others.